# Mapear array de 2 dimensiones Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

Necesito mapear una lista de string en una array bi dimencional para despues recorrerlo

```
  List<List<String>> matriz;
   arrayPasos.asMap().forEach((i, value) {
    arrayMensaje = value.split(';');
    arrayMensaje.asMap().forEach( (index, value) {
        matriz[i][index] = arrayMensaje[index];
    });
  });
```

Tengo esto pero me sale error: "the method [] was callled on null"
como ejemplo la lista de string contiene datos como estos 
[
'1red1;3yellow',
'2green;1purple;3red;6purple'
]
cada indice lo debo separar en un array con un split(';')

PD: El problema se origina al mapear el array generado en el split()

edit: los datos deben quedar asi:

```
 ['1red', '3yellow'],
['2green','1purple','3red','6purple' ]
```

cada string por separado

Comment: Podrías dar más info,  ya pusiste los datos de entrada, ahora indica como debería quedar la matriz o como esperas que quede

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que estás poniendo los valores en la `matriz` cuando esta matriz aún no está definida.

Para agregar elementos a lista lo tienes que hacer usando el método `add`, el código quedaría así :

```dart
void main() {
  final arrayPasos =  [ '1red;3yellow', '2green;1purple;3red;6purple' ] ;
 List<List<String>> matriz = List();
   arrayPasos.asMap().forEach((i, value) {
    final arrayMensaje = value.split(';');
    final subList = List<String>();
    arrayMensaje.asMap().forEach( (index, value) {
        subList.add(arrayMensaje[index]);      
    });
      matriz.add(subList);
  });


  for(List<String> row in matriz){
    print(row);
  }
}
```